# Spring Boot app returns "Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession'" and NoHostAvailableException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm writing a `Springboot` project to implement `ISO20022` which uses `cassandra db`.

My `POM.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Simple Wallet</name>
    <description>Powered with ISO20022</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My `Cassandra` config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "org.example.repository")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "isodb";
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = super.cluster();
        cluster.setContactPoints("127.0.0.1");
        cluster.setPort(9142);
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping() {
        return new CassandraMappingContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean getMetricsEnabled() { return false; }

}
```

`appliction.properties:`

```
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=isodb
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=create_if_not_exists
```

Output of running `cassandra`'s nodetool status:

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  69.07 KiB  16      100.0%            34bb5a10-bd19-46ea-8ece-a68b239becf4  rack1
```

When I run the project, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: \
  Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource \
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: \
    Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is \
    com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: \ 
    All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042 \
    (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: \
    [localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042] Cannot connect), localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 \
    (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: \
    [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
```

How can I fix this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

So seeing this:

```
Cannot connect), localhost/127.0.0.1:9042
```

And this:

```
cluster.setContactPoints("127.0.0.1");
cluster.setPort(9142);
```

Not sure which port Cassandra is expecting connections on, but 9142 is only used for SSL in versions >= 4.0.  Otherwise, it's 9042.  Also, I would not specify the port or contact points in the code, but rather in the `src/main/resources/application.[yaml|properties]` file.  It's possible that those settings are conflicting.

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
```

Additionally, the Java version of the Cassandra JVM does not have to match the JVM version used in the service layer code.  I'd *highly* recommend using at least Java 17.

So the next, big thing that I see is that the `spring-boot-starter-parent` version is about 5 years old:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Spring Boot version 3 isn't binary compatible with 2.x, so for now I'd recommend using 2.7.10:

```
<version>2.7.10</version>
```

I'm guessing that you'll also have to make the same version adjustment with `spring-boot-autoconfigure`.

Setting this parent version properly should bring in the correct driver to work with Cassandra 4.0.8.

**Edit**

So I don't think you need that `CassandraConfig` class.  As long as you build your repositories so they extend `ReactiveCassandraRepository` and define the connection properties in the `application.properties` file, it should just work.

Baeldung has an article stepping through how to use the Spring Boot Cassandra Reactive library, and I'd advise taking a look through that: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cassandra-reactive

Comment: I replaced `9142` with `9042` and removed `<java.version>1.8</java.version>` from `pom.xml`, but I'm still getting same error...

Comment: I've updated the question with my `application.properties`

Comment: Sure, please check https://justpaste.it/69rpj

Comment: just wondering if my dependencies for `cassandra` are correct... Please recheck `pom.xml`

Comment: I did that, getting these errors now: `Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.7.10' not found` and `Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.7.10' not found`

Comment: @AjayKulkarni Running a `mvn clean install` should pull down the new version.

Comment: Did that, getting another error: `java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class CassandraClusterFactoryBean`, is it related to `update cassandra to 4.3 guide` - https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.3/upgrade_guide/?? Can you please point me to a proper `cassandra config` file?

Answer (score 1):

The `TransportException` is a very specific error thrown by the Java driver which means that it cannot reach the cluster. This is a clear indication that your app cannot connect to the cluster on IP `127.0.0.1` on CQL port `9042`.

It is important to note that if your application is not running on the same host as the Cassandra node, it will not be able to connect. By definition, `localhost` is only reachable on the local host.

Otherwise, you need to investigate why there is no network connectivity between your app and the cluster. A good way to troubleshoot is by running Linux utilities like `lsof` or `netstat` to verify that the Cassandra instance is indeed (1) running on `localhost`, and (2) listening on port `9042`.

Run one of the following commands and review the output to verify the IP + port for the Cassandra process:

```
$ sudo lsof -nPi -sTCP:LISTEN
```

```
$ netstat -tnlp
```